# How to send Image from database to gallery android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to android and I'm coding an app, and I want to get an image from my database and send it to the gallery I know how to do the opposite but this I have no idea what to do or how to start.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
public class ImageStorageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // DATABASE
    public static DatabaseManager databaseManager;
    final int REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY = 999;
    ImageView imageView;

    // grid view
    GridView gridView;
    ArrayList<Photo> list;
    Photoadapter adapter = null;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_image_storage);


        imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);


        CreateDatabase(); // create the database
        gridView();

    }

    public void CreateDatabase() {
        databaseManager = new DatabaseManager(this, "Image.db", null, 1);
        databaseManager.queryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Image(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, image BLOB)");
        Log.d("DATABASE", "Database was created");
    }

    private void update() {
        // get all data from sqlite
        Cursor cursor = ImageStorageActivity.databaseManager.getData("SELECT * FROM Image");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);

            list.add(new Photo(id, image));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void gridView(){
        gridView =  findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new Photoadapter(this, R.layout.photo_list, list);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        gridView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        Log.d("gridView", "gridView is working");

        // get all data from sqlite
        final Cursor cursor = ImageStorageActivity.databaseManager.getData("SELECT * FROM Image");
        list.clear();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int id = cursor.getInt(0);
            byte[] image = cursor.getBlob(1);
            list.add(new Photo( id,image));
        }
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d("data", "get all data from sqlite");


        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                CharSequence[] items = {"Delete"};
                AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageStorageActivity.this);

                dialog.setTitle("Choose an action");
                dialog.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                        if (item == 0) {
                            // delete
                            Cursor c = ImageStorageActivity.databaseManager.getData("SELECT id FROM Image");
                            ArrayList<Integer> arrID = new ArrayList<>();
                            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                                arrID.add(c.getInt(0));
                            }
                            showDialogDelete(arrID.get(position));
                        }
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    private void showDialogDelete(final int idImage) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder dialogDelete = new AlertDialog.Builder(ImageStorageActivity.this);

        dialogDelete.setTitle("Warning!!");
        dialogDelete.setMessage("Are you sure you want to this delete?");
        dialogDelete.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                try {
                    ImageStorageActivity.databaseManager.fetch(idImage);

                    ImageStorageActivity.databaseManager.deleteData(idImage);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete successfully!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                }
                update();
            }
        });

        dialogDelete.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialogDelete.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_image, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        RelativeLayout Main_view =  findViewById(R.id.main_view);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add: {
                try{
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                            ImageStorageActivity.this,
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
        return byteArray;
    }

    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY){
            if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY);
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You don't have permission to access file location!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return;
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            Uri uri = data.getData();

            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                databaseManager.insertData(imageViewToByte(imageView));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
                getContentResolver().delete(uri,null,null);
                update();

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

Here's my database

```
public class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DatabaseManager(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    public void queryData(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        database.execSQL(sql);
    }

    public void insertData( byte[] image ) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "INSERT INTO IMAGE VALUES (NULL,? ,?)";
        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();


        statement.bindBlob(1,image);

        statement.executeInsert();

    }

    public void updateData(byte[] image , int id ){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();

        String sql ="UPDATE  IMAGE SET  image = ? WHERE id = ? ";
        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);

        statement.bindBlob(1,image);
        statement.bindDouble(2,(double)id);

        statement.execute();
        database.close();
    }
    public  void deleteData(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();

        String sql = "DELETE FROM IMAGE WHERE id = ?";
        SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(sql);
        statement.clearBindings();
        statement.bindDouble(1, (double)id);

        statement.execute();
        database.close();
    }

    public Cursor getData(String sql){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        return database.rawQuery(sql,null);

    }
    public Cursor fetch(int id){
        SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
        String sql = "SELECT  FROM IMAGE WHERE id = ? ";
        Cursor c = database.rawQuery(sql,null);
        return  c ;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code to convert from blob to byte array and then use that byte array to create bitmap which you can show in imageview.

```
byte[] byteArray = DBcursor.getBlob(columnIndex);  

Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0 ,byteArray.length);
```

Comment: i need to send the bitmap to gallery and not put it in an imageview